# Как не повторять строки в БД?

Tags: jquery, php

Есть таблица, в нее вводятся данные формы. Но перед формированием формы, скрипт, если не передано ID строки, записывает пустую строку в таблицу и передает форме ее ID  в скрытое поле. Соответственно, при каждом F5 добавляется новая строка в таблицу. А если передать скрипту ID, то в форму загружает уже существующие данные из таблицы.

Как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении страницы новая строка не добавлялась в таблицу. При этом надо учесть, что одновременно могут открыть несколько таких форм и каждая форма загружается в tabs от JQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решение рождается из предположения, что один и тот же пользователь за очень маленькое время не сможет отправить два раза форму, заполнив ее. Если он это делает, значит перезагружает страницу.

```
<input type='hidden' name='antirepeat' value='<?=md5(session_id().microtime())?>' />
```

PHP:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['antirepeat'])){
$_SESSION['antirepeat'] = $_POST['antirepeat'];
 //record form data
}else{
if($_SESSION['antirepeat'] != $_POST['antirepeat']){
//record form data
}else{
//log system error: repeated form
}
}
```

Улучшения: если вместо microtime() брать, скажем, ceil(time()/100), то можно запретить постить форму(даже разную) чаще, чем в 100 секунд.

В представленном варианте, пользователь не ограничивается в количестве заполненных форм, но ограждается от ошибки повторного занесения.

Comment: Не могу переварить. Но чувствую, что это не мой случай.

Comment: Пришел юзер. Увидел кнопку "открыть форму для заполнения". Нажал на нее 100500 раз. Открылось 100500 табов. Клик мыши - 30-50мс, Создание новой формы - 1-10мс. В итоге, у каждой формы, открытой таким образом будет РАЗНЫЙ antirepeat.

Теперь он заполнил одну из форм, отправил на обработку, потом случайно нажал F5. Так как форма не пересоздавалась, а только отправилась заново, antirepeat у нее имеет ТО же значение, что и при создании. См выше: в штатном режиме такого не бывает. Значит с таким сабмитом мы его посылаем.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не полностью понял суть вопроса, но что если не добавлять в таблицу новую строку, а высчитывать значение нового ID = max(id) + 1 и помещать в скрытое поле. Соответственно, перед записью, проверять на наличие подобного ID и далее смотря по результату...

Comment: Вы правильно поняли, но если делать так, то одновременно несколько таких форм не получится редактировать. А клиент может сразу 15 таких форм открыть в табы, и у всех будет один и тот же ID. А надо чтобы были уникальные, потому что яваскрипт функции должны знать какую форма редактируется из 15 открытых.

Comment: Может при открытии новых таб вызывать тоже действие, что и призагрузке формы, а при их закрытии, если не был отправлен запрос удалять пустые строки.

Comment: Закрытие тут непричем, важен факт обновления (F5).

Answer (score 0):

1. Уверен что вы плохо продумали логику работы всего приложения раз у вас возникла такая ситуайция.
2. Избежать дублей в базе данных на самом деле очень просто. Задайте индекс по нескольким ключевым полям как уникальные. При попытке инсерта строки, индексы в которой совпадут, серевер базы данных вернет ошибку.